# HttpException - File Does Not Exist

Tags: asp.net

I'm having  a bit of an odd occurrence. Intermittantly I'm seeing file not found exceptions being generated for requests to a certain page. Here is the exception

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The file '/xyz.aspx' does not
>   exist. at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp) at
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) at
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

The odd thing is that this is being thrown by the page xyz.aspx. I'm a little bemused with it - if the page truly didn't exist then I would expect to see a 404. There are no streamreaders/writers attempting to physically load the file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So actually you are opening the url /xyz.aspx and get that message displayed? If yes then that's the normal 404 page you see from an ASP.NET webserver hosted on IIS

Comment: Not exactly. The ASP.NET pipeline tries to find the handler for the request that ends with `/xyz.aspx`, which is actually the page itself, unless you've routed the request to some other URL. If it can't find this handler, you get the error. It's not a 404 because the request didn't even get handled. I expect that the actual status code returned is 500. So, does `xyz.aspx` exist or not?

Comment: xyz.aspx exists - I would have expected it to get handles by iis since 404, 403, 410, 500 are all handled normally.

Comment: We see this hundreds of times a week.  Now, for us this is caused by people using old links or even trying to hack our servers.  I am working to trap these so they do not fall into this unhandled exception like you are getting.